# Perlin Noise: Calculating pseudorandom gradients of grid points

Tags: random, vector, gradient, noise, perlin-noise

I seem to be having a bit of an issue understanding [this](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html#toc-algorithm) Perlin Noise article.  I need some help understanding how calculating the pseudorandom gradients for each bounding point works.  The author gives the function:

```
g(xgrid, ygrid) = (gx, gy)
```

Then he gives the image:

[image: 4 pseudorandom gradients?]

I understand the rest of the article, but I have no idea how he generates these random gradients from each bounding point.  Assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I have no idea how he generates these random gradients from each bounding point.

From the article, it uses a pseudorandom number generator with always the same seed, and calculates it always on the same grid, so that

> we mean that g has the *appearance* of randomness, but with the important consideration
>   that it always returns the same gradient for the same grid point, every time it's
>   calculated. It's also important that every direction has an equal chance of being
>   picked.

So probably it does something like

```
srand(CONSTANT_VALUE);

for (y = 0; y < GridHeight; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < GridWidth; x++)
    {
        r1 = rand();
        r2 = rand();
        gradient[y][x] = some_function(r1, r2);
    }
}
```

so that in each point the gradient is pseudorandom, it is always the same for the same x and y, and is distributed evenly. It then accesses the matrix `gradient` to run the rest of the calculations.

Comment: Good answer but in all the implementations of Perlin Noise I've seen, nothing like that has been used.  'Gradients' don't seem to be true gradients.  But I am not sure.

Comment: Agree that they don't look much like gradients - I'd call them rather *vectors*. Or even *versors*, they look like they're fixed length. Still, that's what HE said :-D

Comment: I think they're gradients in the sense that they represent the rate of change of the noise at that point, like a "normal" vector.  Fixed-length is what helps the maxima of the noise to be consistent.  If they were truly random the noise would have dull spots.   I think.